# Google Glass Entreprise Edition 2 : Failed to Initialize Debug Data

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-glass-camera

I am having the following error displayed on Android Studio when using the Camera2 API with the Google Glass Entreprise Edition 2:

> E/CamX: [ERROR][CORE   ] camxpipeline.cpp:1606 InitializeDebugDataBuffer() Failed to Initialize Debug Data

This does not prevent me to capture images but

This issue is only observed on this platform (already tried with Vuzix blade and Samsung Note 9). I also tried using the CameraX API but the output error is also present.

This happens whether I am using the AutoExposure mode in Android or when I am setting manual parameters to the camera.

The following example illustrate how it is done when requesting for AutoExposure :

```java
// Add a new request ( could be AutoExposure or a Specific ISO or Shutter Speed)
mCaptureRequest.put(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);

// Stop the Repeating Request
mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
// Abort Captures
mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();

// For each data in my request add it to the request builder
    for (HashMap.Entry<CaptureRequest.Key<?>, Object> request : mCaptureRequest.entrySet()) {
                      mPreviewRequestBuilder.set((CaptureRequest.Key<Boolean>) request.getKey(), (boolean) request.getValue());
    }
// Set the repeating request
    mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

How can I remove this error ? It doesn't prevent me to visualize or to make some image processing behind, yet the platform seems to suffer from slow processing when capturing images from the camera so I am looking at every issue possible.

Answer (score 1):

The number of 'error' logs that a typical camera implementation on an Android device produces is quite large, unfortunately.

Most of them are harmless (until one isn't, of course!) so unless you clearly see a problem from this one, I would recommend you just ignore it.

(For example, this may be a debugging log framework initializing, but it's not set up to work on retail builds, but nobody got around to removing the error message that fires up when it tries to start)